# Queries on multiple database with codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, multiple-databases

I have 2 databases, and I would like to make a query with the 2 databases, like for example

```
SELECT base1.table1.item1 FROM base1.table1 INNER JOIN base2.table3 ON base2.table3.item2 = base1.table1.item2 WHERE base2.table3.item4 = 'toto';
```

How to make this query with codeIgniter ?
I already have configured database.php in CodeIgniter with the 2 databases.

Thanks.

Comment: just mention db name before the table like in your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can setup 2 database in config/database.php file

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'first_db',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);

//set second db configuration 
$db['otherdb'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'second_db',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

> When you want use default database means master database

```
// use master dataabse
$users = $this->db->get('users');

// connect to secondary database
 $otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
 $data = $otherdb->get('table_name');
```

> if your first db name is base1 and second is base2

```
$this->db->select('table1.item1 FROM table1');
                 $this->db->from('table1');
                 $this->db->join('base2.table3', 'base2.table3.item2 =table1.item2');
$this->where('base2.table3.item4','toto')
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: But how to make sql joins ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it !

Comment: just use second database table  with database_name.table_name

Comment: Hi is it possible to configure the secound database after? So i land on my index, and i get some variables and i want to use those variables to build another database is it possible to do it?